# No funciona consulta CREATE TABLE mysql

Tags: mysql

Tengo esta consulta MySQL que intento realizar y por alguna razón no anda. ¿Alguno puede ver el error? He leído desde ayer otras preguntas y no encuentro la respuesta. No encuentro mi error realmente.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS empleados2(
  'personaId' int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  'nombre' text(11),
  'apellido' text(11),
  'direccion' text(20),
  'cargo' text(20),
  'sueldo_bruto' double(11),
  'cargas_sociales' double(11),
  'vacaciones' double(11),
  'sueldo_neto' double(11)
);
```

También he intentado ésta, pero tampoco va:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS empleados2(
  'personaId' int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  'nombre' text(11),
  'apellido' text(11),
  'direccion' text(20),
  'cargo' text(20),
  'sueldo_bruto' double(11),
  'cargas_sociales' double(11),
  'vacaciones' double(11),
  'sueldo_neto' double(11),
  PRIMARY KEY('personaId')
);
```

Comment: Siempre es importante incluir el error que recibes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Son 2 problemas principales que tienes:

Primero, no se deben usar comillas simples para los nombres de las columnas. O no usas nada, o puedes usar *back ticks*.  O sea, en vez de:

```
'personaId' int(11)
```

...puedes usar

```
`personaId` int(11)
```

... o

```
personaId int(11)
```

El segundo problema es que al tipo `double` no le puedes especificar un tamaño. O sea que:

```
vacaciones double(11)
```

... no es correcto, sino que debería ser simplemente:

```
vacaciones double
```

... o tal vez tu intención era usar otro tipo.  En cualquier caso, tienes que corregir el problema en todas la columnas donde estás usando el tipo `double` erróneamente.

De modo que una vez aplicado las correcciones (usando tu primer intento como base), la sentencia sería:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS empleados2(
    personaId int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    nombre text(11), 
    apellido text(11), 
    direccion text(20), 
    cargo text(20), 
    sueldo_bruto double, 
    cargas_sociales double, 
    vacaciones double, 
    sueldo_neto double);
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://rextester.com/QYO58843)</kbd>

Comment: Excelente, gracias @sstan

Comment: so knowledge, much right